# selecting individual rows from gridview using check box

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview that contains a check box inside the template field. I want to retrieve the values of the rows where the check box is checked so I can update them through the database. Here's my code:

```
    protected void approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Select")).Checked) 
            {
```

//I thought if the loop finds a checked check box, it will execute the following to that row:

```
                con.Open();

                string approve = "update table set status ='Approved' where ID=" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "";

                SqlCommand scmapprove = new SqlCommand(approve, con);

                scmapprove.ExecuteNonQuery();

                view();

                con.Close();

            }

                            }
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. For example I checked five rows from the table, It only updates the first row. What should I do?

Comment: Did you bind ID with second column or first? Your code looks fine! Could it be that you need `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text`  ?

Comment: Hi afzalulh, I tried that and it said ID cannot be found. I asume it's because the check box is in row 0?

Comment: What is `view();`? Are you rebinding the Gridview by this?

Comment: Yes. It is a function.

Comment: That is the issue. After rebinding all rows are regenerated. So, bind the GridView after completing checking and updating database. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rebinding the Gridview after finding a checked row. Bind it after completing all update operations:

```
protected void approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Select")).Checked) 
        {
            //I thought if the loop finds a checked check box, it will execute the following to that row:
            con.Open();
            string approve = "update table set status ='Approved' where ID=" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "";

            SqlCommand scmapprove = new SqlCommand(approve, con);
            scmapprove.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //view(); //Donot rebind the gridview now.
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    view();
}
```